# Why my scrapy response body is empty?

Tags: scrapy

I'm learning scrapy recently. And I tried use its simplist way to fetch a response body, but I got an empty string.

Here is my code:

```
>>> from scrapy.http import Response
>>> r = Response('http://zenofpython.blog.163.com/blog/static/23531705420146124552782')
>>> r.body
''
>>> r.headers
{}
>>> r.status
200
```

And with no difficulty, I can visit the url I used above for scrapy Response through browser.It has rich content.

What mistake I've made here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to fetch a `Request` and get a `Response` object in return.

Try doing:

```
r = Request(url='http://zenofpython.blog.163.com/blog/static/23531705420146124552782')
fetch(r)
```

on `scrapy shell` and you'll be able to get the result as a `Response` object.

```
print response.body
```

Answer (score 3):

Another reason for your problem can be that the site requires `User-Agent` header. Try it like this

```
scrapy shell http://www.to.somewhere -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9) Gecko/20080705 Firefox/3.0 Kapiko/3.0'
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509577/empty-list-with-scrapy-and-xpath)