# Empty list with scrapy and Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm starting to use scrapy and xpath to scrape some page, I'm just trying  simple things  using ipython, an I get response in some pages like in IMDB, but when I try in others like www.bbb.org I always get an empty list. This is what I'm doing:

```
scrapy shell 'http://www.bbb.org/central-western-massachusetts/business-reviews/auto-repair-and-service/toms-automotive-in-fitchburg-ma-211787'
```

> BBB Accreditation
>
> A BBB Accredited Business since 02/12/2010
>
> BBB has determined that Tom's Automotive meets BBB accreditation standards, which include a commitment to......"

the xpath of this paragraph is:

```
'//*[@id="business-accreditation-content"]/p[2]'
```

So I use:

```
data = response.xpath('//*[@id="business-accreditation-content"]/p[2]').extract()
```

But `data` is an empty list, I'm getting the Xpath with chrome and it works in other pages, but here I get nothing regardless what part of the page I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website actually checks for the `User-Agent` header.

See what it returns if you don't specify it:

```
$ scrapy shell 'http://www.bbb.org/central-western-massachusetts/business-reviews/auto-repair-and-service/toms-automotive-in-fitchburg-ma-211787'
In [1]: print(response.body)
Out[1]: 123

In [2]: response.xpath('//*[@id="business-accreditation-content"]/p[2]').extract()
Out[2]: []
```

Yes, that's right - the response contains only `123` if there is an unexpected request user agent.

Now with the header (note the specified `-s` command-line argument):

```
$ scrapy shell 'http://www.bbb.org/central-western-massachusetts/business-reviews/auto-repair-and-service/toms-automotive-in-fitchburg-ma-211787' -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36'
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@id="business-accreditation-content"]/p[2]').extract()
Out[1]: [u'<p itemprop="description">BBB has determined that Tom\'s Automotive meets <a href="http://www.bbb.org/central-western-massachusetts/for-businesses/about-bbb-accreditation/bbb-code-of-business-practices-bbb-accreditation-standards/" lang="LS30TPCERNY5b60c87311af50cf82720b237d8ef866">BBB accreditation standards</a>, which include a commitment to make a good faith effort to resolve any consumer complaints. BBB Accredited Businesses pay a fee for accreditation review/monitoring and for support of BBB services to the public.</p>']
```

This was an example from the shell. In a real Scrapy project, you would need to set the [`USER_AGENT` project setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent). Or, you may also use user agent rotation with the help of this middleware: [`scrapy-fake-useragent`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-fake-useragent/).